# Fetch artifacts from other job using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get up to speed with the new Jenkins Declarative Pipelines, and I'm using our current workflow as an example.

We could potentially do multiple builds, depending on the stream that the developers are working on at the time, and would then deploy different builds to different environments, for example, a hotfix for live would be in testing, while the new release may be in the dev environment.

This worked well with older version of Jenkins + the promote plugin, because we could simply promote a specific build to a deploy job for a particular environment. Did some googling, and doesn't look like there is a promote equivalent for the new Jenkins Pipelines.

This means we are back to using a "build" job and a "deploy" job. Now, I'm trying to wrap my head around the new declarative pipelines that's being pushed quite hard, and I've head a dead-end with artifacts.

Since build & deploy are now separate jobs, we would have to copy the artifacts from one job to the other. I've found numerous answers on how to use the CopyArtifact class, but I have no idea how to access this using the new declarative pipelines.

Here is my "Build" job:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') { 
      steps { 
        sh 'echo 123 > testing.txt'
      }
    }
    stage('Archive') {
      steps {
        milestone 10
        archive 'testing.txt'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my "Deploy" pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Fetch Artifact') {
      step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'Build', filter: 'testing.txt'])
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh './deploy testing.txt'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running that fails, since Jenkins Declarative pipelines expect "steps" to be a block.

I've tried:

```
steps {
  $class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'Build', filter: 'testing.txt'
}
```

But I'm getting "unexpected token"

EDIT:

Thanks to Christopher, I've made some progress, but with the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate={$class=CopyArtifact, projectName=Build, filter=testing.txt}} for CoreStep(delegate: SimpleBuildStep{ArtifactArchiver(artifacts: String, allowEmptyArchive?: boolean, caseSensitive?: boolean, defaultExcludes?: boolean, excludes?: String, fingerprint?: boolean, onlyIfSuccessful?: boolean) | Fingerprinter(targets: String) | GitHubCommitNotifier(resultOnFailure: String, statusMessage?: ExpandableMessage(content: String)) | GitHubCommitStatusSetter(commitShaSource?: GitHubCommitShaSource{BuildDataRevisionShaSource() | ManuallyEnteredShaSource(sha: String)}, contextSource?: GitHubStatusContextSource{DefaultCommitContextSource() | ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource(context: String)}, errorHandlers?: StatusErrorHandler{ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler(result: String) | ShallowAnyErrorHandler()}[], reposSource?: GitHubReposSource{AnyDefinedRepositorySource() | ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource(url: String)}, statusBackrefSource?: GitHubStatusBackrefSource{BuildRefBackrefSource() | ManuallyEnteredBackrefSource(backref: String)}, statusResultSource?: GitHubStatusResultSource{ConditionalStatusResultSource(results: ConditionalResult{AnyBuildResult(message?: String, state?: String) | BetterThanOrEqualBuildResult(message?: String, result?: String, state?: String)}[]) | DefaultStatusResultSource()}) | GitHubSetCommitStatusBuilder(contextSource?: GitHubStatusContextSource{DefaultCommitContextSource() | ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource(context: String)}, statusMessage?: ExpandableMessage(content: String)) | JUnitResultArchiver(testResults: String, allowEmptyResults?: boolean, healthScaleFactor?: double, keepLongStdio?: boolean, testDataPublishers?: TestDataPublisher{}[]) | JavadocArchiver(javadocDir: String, keepAll: boolean) | Mailer(recipients: String, notifyEveryUnstableBuild: boolean, sendToIndividuals: boolean)}): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named CopyArtifact
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:194)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:385)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:177)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:384)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:284)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:94)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:316)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:215)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:214)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:91)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor331.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor723.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named CopyArtifact
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:425)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:379)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:318)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:194)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    ... 35 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm getting "unexpected token"

Better would have been the full error message, as it shows *which* token is unexpected, and where.

You're correct that all build steps need to be in a `steps` block.  Unfortunately, the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) currently still uses the old `step([$class: 'SomeClass'])` syntax (rather than something like just `copyArtifacts`), but it's still a step, and so needs to go inside the `steps` block, e.g.:

```
stage('Fetch Artifact') {
  steps {
    step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'Build', filter: 'testing.txt'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that seems sensible enough, but I think it's as you pointed out, due to the plugin still using the old step syntax it's not working as expected. Using your syntax I'm getting the following (very verbose) errors.

Comment: That message sounds like you don't have the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) installed.

Comment: Yup, it's installed. Writing the groovy script in the older non-Declarative format seems to solve the problem. So, for now it appears that's the way I need to go until all the plugins have caught up. Thanks for the useful input Christopher.

Comment: Hmm… running the Declarative code I wrote here worked at the time when I tried it. I've seen one or two other features break in the latest release of the Declarative plugins; perhaps it's related.